# ZF2 JS localization

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, zend-framework2

Project written on ZF2. Question is how to implement i18n support for client-side js files? For server-side we are using getText (.po/.mo files).
in onBootstrap()

```
    $translator = $services->get('MvcTranslator');
    // determine locale by browser setting HTTP 'Accept-Language'
    $translator ->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
        ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
```

I don't know how can i get into js files locale settings from ZF2.Some ajax request maybe? I'm thinking about generating JSON file for i18n(en_US.js, ja_JP.js) locale needs to be set in JS or in DOM. Also maybe i should use some javascript i18n framework for pluralization and etc ?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can handle this is to put your JavaScript in view script(s) and return them from a route instead of public. For example `http://your host.com/js/somescript`. This has the benefit of allowing you to use a unified translation workflow. Of course it has the drawback of not allowing you to minify your js so easily.

Comment: Since i'm only implementing lozalization(i'm not ZF2 programmer) - i don't know even how to do it..
Should i put it to Application/View/<new js folder> ? but then how to load it as it was before ? example of module.config.php would be great if configuration is there. 
2. Any other suggestions ? If i have to generate JSON file with translation, how to get ZF2 locale from these JS files? ZF locale is determined by HTTP "Accept-Language" header.